# HTML keeping images inside row without overflowing it

Tags: html, css, image, containers, aurelia

[image: HTML + Aurelia screenshot]

```
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
    <div repeat.for="pw of lstPainelWidgets" class="col ${getPanelCol($index)} p-0">
        <img class="my-img" src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1"
        width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to keep 4 images (which must be in a single row) inside a fluid-container div but my images keep overflowing it. The goal is for the images to adapt to the container (like object-fit: contain) and fill it, instead of ignoring its max-height limits.

I already tried img-fluid, img-responsive, max-height: 100%, but the images ignore all these options and keep overflowing both the row div and the fluid container!

Comment: Please put your code in the question. [help] [ask]

Comment: I should have explained that better. Please copy/paste the code into the question. It is very difficult for those that want to help you to work with just an image of the code.

Comment: Imagine yourself trying to help and typing what you see on an average screenshot, i don't myself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use max-width and max-height instead of height and width.

```
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
    <div repeat.for="pw of lstPainelWidgets" class="col ${getPanelCol($index)} p-0">
        <img class="my-img" src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" max-width="100%" max-height="100%">
      <img class="my-img " src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" max-width="100%" max-height="100%">
      <img class="my-img" src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" max-width="100%" max-height="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

by using flex you can also...

```
<div cass="container">
    <div class="d-flex ">
      <div class="p-2 flex-fill bd-highlight">
        <img class="my-img img-fluid" src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" max-width="100%" max-height="100%">
       </div>
      <div class="p-2 flex-fill bd-highlight">
        <img class="my-img img-fluid" src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" max-width="100%" max-height="100%">
       </div>
      <div class="p-2 flex-fill bd-highlight">
        <img class="my-img img-fluid" src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" max-width="100%" max-height="100%">
       </div>
      <div class="p-2 flex-fill bd-highlight">
        <img class="my-img img-fluid" src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/graphdown.jpg?w=730&crop=1" max-width="100%" max-height="100%">
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I already tried that... But thanks anyway

Comment: if you don't mind , you can try using flex. which i have also added in answer .

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately. The image isn't resizing properly.

Comment: please take a look at my pen https://codepen.io/md-asaduzzaman-muhid/pen/VwLKbdw it is working

Comment: I used template-grid and its working. But thank you anyway!!